# how can i use more than 1 mongodb clusters in node js with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have  backend server where user signup and provide his db cluster details and when a user come with that person,s key i want to find the cluster from my db and write data on provided cluster i can achieve this with `mongoose.connect` but that is slow is there any other way i can connect multiple db clusters in mongoose?

I searched on google i came across with `mongoose.create` connection and `con.usedb` but its for diffrent dbs in same clusters.
i tried on google but could not find any thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to mention your cluster in the URL.
different mongo accounts can be used through different URLs.

Comment: can you explain it or any code snippet for this